# How to import android websocket library in android studio?

Tags: android, libraries

I know the procedure in eclipse but in android studio it's difficult

This is the link of library

https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

Comment: can you describe what you have done/tried so far

Comment: There is also a github project which uses gradle, if that is your problem. https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets

Comment: But please provide more informations about you actual problem.

Comment: I imported it in eclipse but i don't know how to do it  in android studio

Comment: @oberflansch dude  i want to know how to add libraries in android studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 3):

The README.md in the library says DEPRECATED big and fat and provides a link to a better solution: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync. If you use this library simply add this line to you gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
```

Comment: but how to add this in my project.  i mean in which folder?

Comment: you don't need to add this to a folder. that's not how the gradle build system works. you specify your dependencies in your build.gradle file and android studio (or rather gradle) downloads and stores them for you. you don't have to worry about anything.

Comment: do i have to include anything in settings.gradle?

Comment: no, only in build.gradle, the file where you defined your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, etc. There should be a block called dependencies { ... } with some dependencies in it. If not, create one and add the dependency from above

Comment: dude it's showing the error  " could not find compile method for arguments[compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+']"

Comment: please post your build.gradle file so we can help you.

Comment: that's the way I meant it. It works for me, so your error has to be somewhere else. Did you try a gradle clean and rebuild?

Comment: this is the code of MainActivity.java  .... 14 errors are showing in this                                    http://hastebin.com/delohacexo.java

Comment: what should i do with this class? can't compile this because of missing classes^^ if you want help give me please a git repo url to clone.

Comment: Can u give the link of yours facebook or google+ profile?

Answer (score 3):

Use this library org.java_websocket

First thing you should import that library in build.gradle

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}
```

then add the implementation in dependency{}

```
implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"
```

Then you can use this code

```
 private void ConnectToWebSocket() {
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = new URI("ws://192.168.1.135:9000/");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            final String message = s;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edittext_chatbox);
                    textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
}
```